# How to run only one specific rule in SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I want to execute only the 'Unused assignments should be removed' rule/check on my Java project. But I don't know how to do it.

I've already tried with 'Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria' and 'Restrict Scope of Coding Rules' but if I want to reach my goal, I should add all the rule except the one that I want to 'Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria'.

So, is there a way to execute only a single rule?

I'm using the following version `sonarqube-8.4.0.35506`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I figured out what you want to achieve, you need a new copy of the root profile and use the new copy, so that you can modify your set of rules as you want.

This answer with steps could help you: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/how-to-deactivate-a-rule-in-sonarqube